# Setting layout programatically does not display items in GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I'm a beginner at Android and I'm building my first app. I'm displaying images in a gridView which has a layout as following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

<GridView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main_gridView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The getView method in the adapter (extending ArrayAdapter) is as follows:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView;

    if(convertView == null){
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, GridLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)); //Always maintain aspect ratio of 1:1.5
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }

    Picasso
            .with(mContext)
            .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
            .fit()
            .into(imageView);

    return imageView;
}
```

With the above layout, nothing gets displayed on the grid.

But,if instead of setting LayoutParams to `MATCH_PARENT` I do something like 
`new GridView.LayoutParams(layout_width, layout_height)` where layout_width and layout_height are predefined to some value, the images are displayed. Any ideas as to why that is happening will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I imported your code and originally I replaced the `Picasso` call with a delayed `Runnable` just to see if there's any issue with the layout. I could see the test images just fine.

So I added the `Picasso` dependency and using the same images (`android.R.drawable` resources) I saw a blank page. So the problem is somewhere in the `Picasso` call. I added the following lines:

```
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
```

to the `Picasso` setup and, sure enough, I saw only the error placeholder.
Watching the `logcat` I could see `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` all over the place. One of the most common topics about this was when requesting images without extension. But there seem to be lots of causes and I haven't used Picasso that much so know it inside out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll have to dig deep to get to the bottom of this one.